# AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'. Did you mean: 'FigureCanvasAgg'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am using

- Windows 10
- PyCharm 2021.3.3 Professional Edition
- python 3.11.5
- matplotlib 3.8.1

How can I permanently resolve this error on my PC without using `matplotlib.use('Agg')` ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data from file, skipping the first row (header)
data = np.loadtxt('cm.dat', skiprows=1)

# Initialize reference point
x0, y0, z0 = data[0]

# Compute squared displacement for each time step
SD = [(x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2 + (z - z0)**2 for x, y, z in data]

# Compute the cumulative average of SD to get MSD at each time step
MSD = np.cumsum(SD) / np.arange(1, len(SD) + 1)

# Generate time steps
t = np.arange(1, len(SD) + 1)

# Create a log-log plot of MSD versus t
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.loglog(t, MSD, marker='o')

plt.title('Mean Squared Displacement vs Time')
plt.xlabel('Time step')
plt.ylabel('MSD')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--")
plt.show()
```

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:/git/RouseModel/tau_plot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\RouseModel\tau_plot.py", line 20, in <module>
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 934, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 464, in new_figure_manager
    _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 441, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
    canvas_class = cast(type[FigureCanvasBase], _get_backend_mod().FigureCanvas)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 280, in _get_backend_mod
    switch_backend(rcParams._get("backend"))  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 343, in switch_backend
    canvas_class = module.FigureCanvas
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'. Did you mean: 'FigureCanvasAgg'?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
#   cm-X     cm-Y    cm-Z
9.507 21.232 9.910
9.092 18.427 7.308
7.994 14.856 4.675
0.533 12.138 -1.163
-0.056 6.735 -5.470
-2.138 4.950 -7.280
0.736 13.076 -10.012
9.516 14.611 -12.470
0.886 17.235 -10.714
-8.954 21.381 -11.735
-7.457 16.042 -16.710
-0.842 13.984 -17.874
-2.799 13.195 -14.247
0.738 14.792 -11.774
5.760 9.218 -10.846
8.406 13.735 -15.946
6.848 12.679 -9.621
13.569 14.036 -6.348
8.665 12.724 -8.238
... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: I just realized you're in a quite old version of PyCharm Pro. You may want to consider updating. Additionally, new version have integration with GitHub copilot. Current version is PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Professional Edition)

Comment: The code in this question runs without issue and generates a plot in the current version of PyCharm Pro.